# Reactjs/Redux Edit functionality not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I built an app and added CRUD functionality and everything works fine except the edit functionality. The problem is when I try to edit its actually hitting the right database and updates the entry but in the react app its just force updates all the entries to particular one entry.

Update Saga :-

```js
function* updateFeedbackSaga(action) {
  try {
    const updateData = yield call(api.feedback.edit, action.payload);
    yield put(actions.updateFeedback(updateData));
    console.log(updateData);
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(actions.updateFeedbackErrors(err.response.data));
  }
}
```

Edit Reducer

```js
import * as actionTypes from "../Actions/types";

const initialState = {
  feedbacks: [],
  feedback: {},
  loading: false
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    
    case actionTypes.UPDATE_FEEDBACK:
      return {
        ...state,
        feedbacks: state.feedbacks.map(
          feedback =>
            feedback.id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : feedback
        )
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Actions

```js
//Edit and update Feedback
export const updateFeedbackRequest = newFeedbackData => ({
  type: actionTypes.UPDATE_FEEDBACK_REQUEST,
  payload: newFeedbackData
});

export const updateFeedback = updatedData => ({
  type: actionTypes.UPDATE_FEEDBACK,
  payload: updatedData
});

export const updateFeedbackErrors = errors => ({
  type: actionTypes.GET_ERRORS,
  payload: errors
});
```

That's how printing

```js
<section className = "feedback">
  <div className = "employees__table" >
  <h4 className = "semi-heading" > Feedback Table < /h4> 
  {
    FeedbackList feedbacks = {feedbacks} />
  } 
  </div> 
</section >

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    feedbackList: selectors.FeedbackSelector(state)
  });
```

HERE ARE THE IMAGES

This is my feedbacklist
[image]

If I edit the first item then state is like this

[image]

My feedbacklist is repeating edited feedback. I don't know where i am doing wrong.

Here is my database
[image]

Here is the working code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/montygoldy/employee-review/tree/master/client

login: montyjatt@gmail.com
password: 12345678

Comment: The only thing I can see that'd cause that behaviour is this line in your reducer: `feedback.id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : feedback`. If for some reason the `id` was the same, all the current items would be replaced with the current item you're editing, which would cause that error. Have you confirmed that only the edited one is matching in that `map()`? And that all the `id`s are different?

Comment: What does show `console.log(updateData);` in your action creator?

Comment: @Jayce444 thanks for the response... I have added the db image and all the id's are different. and also edit is hitting the right api end point  meaning it actually updates the db and If I clear the state and log in again I see the changes.

Comment: @dhilt  its the form data. I checked it .

Comment: Btw it will be nice to see the result of the update call. Also, I don't understand your component's code: something's not ok around `FeedbackList` tag and the relation between `feedbacks` and `feedbackList` is not obvious...

Comment: @dhilt I just added the relevant code regarding feedbackList. AS you can see in picture they are working fine. the problem I am unable to understand is my action is editing and updating db but on react state it just prints the edited feedback and if

Comment: I log out and log in again I see the new updated feedback

Comment: I have added the working code..

Comment: @MontyGoldy Sandbox is cool! I can't login, getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at loginSaga$`

Comment: @dhilt please use email: "montyjatt@gmail.com" and password: "12345678". Just checked in incognito mode its working

Comment: @MontyGoldy I can't login due to `Request URL: http://localhost:3001/api/users/login`, the endpoint should not be at localhost, I guess, otherwise nobody but you could use it

Comment: Yeah I got it what should i do now .. I need to deploy my backend . Ok I have just updated the routes to normal routes. Now you can access "/dashboard"

Answer (score 0):

## do you need to loop over all feedback when you already know the updated I'd?

```
case actionTypes.UPDATE_FEEDBACK:
 return { 
    ...state,
    feedbacks[action.payload.id]: action.payload.body
    };
```

This will only update a single item because the ID is part of the key.
The way you have it currently the feedbacks will all be replaced by the single value that matches the ID.

If you're planning on sending multiple id's then you'll want to use the spread operator.

```
case actionTypes.UPDATE_FEEDBACK:
 return { 
    ...state,
    feedbacks: {
        ...state.feedbacks,    
        ...action.payload
     }
  };
```

In this case you're spreading out the old feedback items and then using the new payload with the spread operator to overwrite only the ones with matching id's.

Of course this means the `action.payload` should match your feedback structure.

Comment: thank you for the response If I try the way you suggested its throwing a syntax error. i cannot use it like this "feedbacks[action.payload.id]". Plus the way I am doing right is If I find a particular feedback with action.payload.id then its gonna update that particular feedback not the whole feedbacks array thats why I am looping.

Answer (score 0):

Ok SO I have found the fix, actually, it's my id reference in the reducer was incorrect.

correct way is

```js
case actionTypes.UPDATE_FEEDBACK:
      return {
        ...state,
        feedbacks: state.feedbacks.map(
          feedback =>
            feedback._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : feedback
        )
      };
```